# Deleting a line from Bash profile

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, python, path

So using terminal I typed in:  nano .bash_profile 
I then have access to the following bash_profile :

GNU nano 2.0.6                                                      File: .bash_profile

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Added by Canopy installer on 2015-09-29
# VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT can be set to '' to make bashprompt show that Canopy is active, otherwise 1
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source '/Users/psa1/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate'

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I would like to **completely** delete the Canopy line from by bash profile since it is messing up pip or twilio downloads for instance. But I don't know how to do that!

Comment: Is that your *actual* .bash_profile?  It appears to be missing the hash marks (#) to comment lines like "setting path" or "Added by Canopy".  That said, Ctrl-K is what's used in nano to delete.

Comment: this is copy paste, if i add the hash it just ends up putting it in bold that's why I took them out

Comment: using ctrl-K just deletes it once, but if you restart terminal the bash_profile remains the same @Allan

Comment: I'm assuming you're saving it, right?

Comment: Yeah definitely ctrl-X and then relaunching terminal

Comment: can you post the contents of `.bashrc` as well?

Comment: so nano .bashrc it's completely empty

Comment: This may be something you want to address with with the Canopy devs.  I've been searching their site and can't find anything related to bash_profile entries.

Answer (score 1):

Safer than deleting would be to add a # to the beginnng of any line you want disabled and commented out.

If you’re not sure about using the editor, the less you change, the better.

Then exit out of your terminal app and start it again to test.

Safest would be to make a new admin account just in case you need to log in with a working user.

Comment: I ended up deleting the canopy line using vim and not nano.I used vim because for some reason the changes made on nano didn't appear when relaunching the terminal. but you're right should have added the hash